# Datum transformation in QGIS Server 3.10

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-server, datum

I have a QGIS project that uses data stored in Web Mercator (*epsg:3857*) spatial reference system. The project itself has *epsg:5514*. To have a better precision I use one of datum transformations that are available for this srs. This datum transformation is set on project level.  On the QGIS Destkop works everything perfectly but when I use the same project in QGIS Server, the data are several meters shifted. It seems that QGIS Server does not work with datum transformation that are specified in project file.